# How can I add loyalty / reward points for customers?

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product

[image: i want to give loyalty : final prices / 10]

How can i add Loyalty/Reward points to customer using soap API in “Magento Enterprise Edition”

Comment: Good question, by the way. Please add some more text and explanation and less small images (which are hard to read) next time :)

Answer (score 2):

Sadly out of the box the `Enterprise_Reward` module doesn't have an API model.

I would creating your own module to work as a wrapper for the core module. All your module will require are the API methods.

I recommend reading http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html to see how you could achieve this.